# UIButton with type Custom loses Click event

Tags: ios, uibutton, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have the following code to create custom iOS UIButton in Xamarin:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        // will have to create a native Custom type of ios button to avoid text dimming
        // when touched

        // logic of element processing from
        // https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/view/

        // except we don't call the base immediately
        // because it will create the Control for us, but we don't want that here
        if (Control == null)
        {
            // instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
            // the SetNativeControl method
            uiBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
            SetNativeControl(uiBtn); // should set Control to the newly created element 
            // and prevent base.OnElementChanged(e) from creating a new element instead
        }

        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        // some button customization code here - it does not matter, the issue happens also without it...
```

The renderer code works fine, but now I do not receive any Clicked events on my Xamarin.Forms button.

How do I restore the lost click functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Finally in Xamarin source code I found this:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2d9288eee6e6f197364a64308183725e7bd561f9/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs

And looking at OnElementChanged I was somewhat surprised that events are attached only when this instance of OnElementChanged creates native element. Not sure, why it is done that way, but at least now I know that if I create a control myself, then I'll have to wire also the click event myself.